# Error "El editor ha encontrado un error inesperado." al intentar programar publicación de post en wordpress version 5.4.x

Tags: php, wordpress, cms

Tengo una blog en wordpress 5.4.2 en produccion, el cual al intentar programar la publicacion de un nuevo post, especificamente al momento de seleccionar un fecha dentro del mes actual me arroja el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mismo error NO aparece cuando selecciono fechas del mes posterior.

Ya verifique la zona horaria y esta correctamente configurado.

Probe desactivando los plugins y cambioando el tema pero el error persiste.

Tambien realice una instalacion de 0 de dicha version de wordpress en mi local y ocurre el mismo error.

Para mas detalles comparto el error que proporciona wordpress:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2023-11-01')

PD: El error se soluciona actualizando la version a la 5.5 pero quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de solucionarlo sin necesidad de actualizar la version. Desde ya muchas gracias. Saludos !

Comment: si no queres actualizar me imagino habría 2 opciones: hacer un diff de ambas versiones y parchar sólo el block editor ( pareciera ser un issue de gutenberg ) ó instalar el plugin classic editor ( desactiva el editor de bloques gutenberg y activa el editor clasico pre v5 )